# MessageChannel class is inaccessable

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, worker

I am trying to create a MessageChannel between two workers in a Flash project, but when I attempt to debug or publish I get an error stating "VerifyError: Error #1014: Class flash.system::MessageChannel could not be found.". I am using Flash Pro, and, as far as I know, have correctly added and selected Flash Player 11.4 as a publishing target. Does anyone know what could be causing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out the issue - I was unaware that the debugger needed to be updated separately. Since the debugger has been updated, everything seems to be working properly.